# PHP ERROR Output in URL Field

Tags: php, variables, path

i have a form with a variable in the action part with a path/filename inside, but
i got allways a 403 Error in the **Url field** of the browser and not the right path.Her the snippet.

```
<?php $Path = './index.php' ?>

<form action="<?php $Path ?>" method="post" id="form_login">
```

Have anyone a Idea whats can be wrong.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 errors i`ve seen.

```
<?php 

$Path = './index.php'; // forgot to end the statement. 

?>
/* forgot to echo and end the statement here */
<form action="<?php echo $Path; ?>" method="post" id="form_login">
```

Comment: Hi, still the url field contains the 403 error instead the path of the variable.

Comment: @dA_uNknOwN you got it when you sumbit the page right? if that so that means your defined path is stated incorrectly..

Comment: @dA_uNknOwN what about file permissions, is index.php writable? Is this code in the same index.php file or it's another file?

Comment: its another index.php in a other directory.

Comment: Its a xampp test environment the File has Permissions

Comment: @dA_uNknOwN another thing i see is you have no permission to access the file `index.php` because of that 403 error. in that point @zack maybe right

Comment: possible solution is create another filename and direct to it so you may not if the error still occurs

Comment: And then the error comes into the url field of the browser ? I thought it  depents on the syntax

Comment: I have checked some empty test.php's but always the 403 error code is in the url field.

Comment: http://ip.com/web/<br%20/><b>Notice</b>:%20%20.....  thats in the url field instead the path of the variable.

Comment: did you done some tweaks on the xampp config or have an .htaccess wirtten?

Comment: just the errore reporting, start up errors display errors on, no htaccess

Comment: `<form action="<?php echo $Path; ?>" method="post" id="form_login">` you have problem on this part just try to hardcode the url if it works

Comment: what u mean with hardcode. if i add manually the path into the action   part it works.

Comment: but i need a if statement  for 3 variants of the action field

Comment: you should post your complete code ..

Comment: ok wait 5 mins i clean up the code, thx  for your time

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ccppgvVE

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo it:

```
<form action="<?php echo $Path ?>" method="post" id="form_login">
```